# Controlling image setting in code using ImageMagick.NET (code equivalent to command line -define)

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

I'm using ImageMagick.Net to write an image. I'm trying to control some settings in the output image. I can't figure out how to modify these settings from code, although they are available in ImageMagick command line ([ImageMagick defines](https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php)).

I'm specifically interested in modifying the "predictor" setting which is by default 3 when the image is compressed using the "Deflate" method.

Sample code:

```
        var collection = new MagickImageCollection(args[0]);
        IWriteDefines tiffWriteDefines= new TiffWriteDefines()
        {
            PreserveCompression = true
        };
        collection.Write(@"d:\outImage.tiff", tiffWriteDefines);
```

These settings are controlled from command line by specifying the

> Magick image.tif -define tiff:predictor=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work I found the answer:
to modify this setting you should go over each of the images in the collection and:

```
foreach (var image in imageCollection)
{
    image.Settings.SetDefine(MagickFormat.Tiff, "predictor", "1");
}
```

this solved the problem for me.